# c3.js scatter plot axis not scaling to adjust for point radius

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I've created a c3 scatter plot that generates points of different sizes depending on the data. If a point near the leftmost or rightmost of the graph is relatively large, it won't be contained within the graph, and part of the point gets cut off. If I add static padding, the graph doesn't scale appropriately for different cases, and will sometimes have far too much or too little padding. Is there a way to contain the points within the graph by dynamically generating the padding?

Code:

```
function getChart(gridData) {

    var colors = ['#b2182b', '#d6604d', '#f4a582', '#fddbc7', '#f7f7f7', '#d1e5f0', '#92c5de', '#4393c3', '#4392c3', '#2166ac'];
    var columns = [];
    var mySize = {};
    var mySizeArray = [];
    var myXs = {};
    var myNames = [];
    var myPointColors;
    myPointColors = {};
    var pointSize;
    var newData = extractPointsFromGrid(gridData);

    pointSize = function (sizeVal, sizes) {
        var Incidence = sizeVal;
        var MIN_incidence = d3.min(sizes);
        var MAX_incidence = d3.max(sizes);
        var qtl3 = d3.mean(sizes);

        //noinspection OverlyComplexArithmeticExpressionJS
        var s = ((Incidence - MIN_incidence) * (50 - 10)) / (MAX_incidence - MIN_incidence) + 3;

        return (s + Math.floor(qtl3) > 3) ? s + Math.floor(qtl3) : 3;
    };

    var bubbleSizes = function (sizes) {
        var _sizes = typeof sizes === 'object' ? sizes : [];
        var len = (typeof _sizes === 'object') ? sizes.length : 0;

        var sizesArray = _.pluck(_sizes, 'iCumulative');

        var reacsArray = _.pluck(_sizes, 'reac');
        var newSizes = [];
        _sizes.forEach(function (size) {

            var newSize = pointSize(Math.abs(size.iCumulative), sizesArray);
            newSizes.push({'reac': size.reac, 'size': newSize});
        });
        window.sizes = newSizes;
        return newSizes;
    };

    var myNameIndex = [];
    var myPointSizes = [];
    var i = 0;

    var myColors = bubbleColors.reverse();
    var myPts = bubbleSizes(newData);
    var dynamicPadding = addDynamicPadding(myPts, newData);

    newData.forEach(function (d) {
        var name = d.reac;
        var myRor = [d.reac];
        var myPs = [d.reac + "_Primary Suspect"];

        myRor.push(d.ROR);
        myPs.push(d.PS);
        myNames.push(d.reac);
        myNameIndex[i] = d.reac;
        myPointColors[d.reac] = myColors[i];

        columns.push(myRor);
        columns.push(myPs);
        myXs[myRor[0]] = myPs[0];
        mySize[d.reac] = d.iCumulative;
        myNameIndex[d.reac] = d.PS;
        myPointSizes.push = {'reac': d.reac, 'size': d.iCumulative};

        i++;
    });

    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#rxsignal-chart-bubble',
        size: {
            height: 200
        },
        data: {
            xs: myXs,
            columns: columns,
            type: 'scatter',
            colors: myPointColors
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                label: 'Primary Suspect Cases',
                tick: {
                    fit: false
                },
                // padding: {top: 200, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}
            },
            y: {
                label: 'ROR',
                tick: {
                    fit: false,
                    format: function (d) {
                        return (d < 0) ? '' : d;
                    }
                },
                // padding: {top: 5, left: 5, right: 100, bottom: 5}
            }
        },
        point: {
            r: function (d) {
                pointSize = _.where(myPts, {reac: d.id})[0];
                return pointSize.size;
            },
            focus: {
                expand: {
                    enabled: false,
                    r: function (d) {
                        return d.r;
                    }
                }

            }
        },
        tooltip: {

            format: {
                title: function (d) {

                    return false;

                },
                name: function (name) {
                    return name;
                },
                value: function (value, ratio, id, size, x) {

                    var numFormat = d3.format(',');
                    var decFormat = d3.format('.');
                    var pctgFormat = d3.format('.4p');

                    return '<tr colspan="2"><td>Primary Suspect Cases</td><td>' + numFormat(myNameIndex[id]) + '</td></tr>' + '<tr><td>ROR</td><td>' + numFormat(value) + '</td></tr>';

                }
            }
        }
    });

    var getPaddingChange = function (chart) {
        var change = {
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0
        };

        var m = chart.internal.main.node().parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
        // the chart area is shifted by this transform - so we need to adjust the point coordinates by this amount
        var t = d3.transform(chart.internal.main.attr("transform")).translate;
        // loop through each point
        chart.internal.main.selectAll('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.circle).each(function () {
            var c = this.getBBox();

            // left clipping
            if (c.x < -t[0])
                change.left = Math.max(change.left, -(c.x + t[0]));
            // right clipping
            if ((c.x + c.width) > (m.width - t[0]))
                change.right = Math.max(change.right, (c.x + c.width) - (m.width - t[0]));
            // top clipping
            if (c.y < -t[1])
                change.top = Math.max(change.top, -(c.y + t[1]));
            // bottom clipping
            if ((c.y + c.height) > (m.height - t[1]))
                change.bottom = Math.max(change.bottom, (c.y + c.height) - (m.height - t[1]));
        })

        return change;
    }

    var change = getPaddingChange(chart);

    chart.internal.config.padding_top = chart.internal.getCurrentPaddingTop() + change.top;
    chart.internal.config.padding_bottom = chart.internal.getCurrentPaddingBottom() + change.bottom;
    chart.internal.config.padding_left = chart.internal.getCurrentPaddingLeft() + change.left;
    chart.internal.config.padding_right = chart.internal.getCurrentPaddingRight() + change.right;
    // force a redraw
    chart.flush();

    // remove clip path
    chart.internal.main.select('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.chart).attr('clip-path', null);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Adjusting C3 Chart Padding to Fit Chart Elements

It would be simpler to adjust the chart padding (instead of the axis padding). This too would ensure that your circles don't get clipped once you remove the clippath

This is the main function that calculates by how much the circles are clipped (if at all) - i.e. it gets you the extra adjustments you need to add to the padding

```
var getPaddingChange = function (chart) {
    var change = {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0
    };

    var m = chart.internal.main.node().parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
    // the chart area is shifted by this transform - so we need to adjust the point coordinates by this amount
    var t = d3.transform(chart.internal.main.attr("transform")).translate;
    // loop through each point
    chart.internal.main.selectAll('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.circle).each(function () {
        var c = this.getBBox();

        // left clipping
        if (c.x < -t[0])
            change.left = Math.max(change.left, -(c.x + t[0]));
        // right clipping
        if ((c.x + c.width) > (m.width - t[0]))
            change.right = Math.max(change.right, (c.x + c.width) - (m.width - t[0]));
        // top clipping
        if (c.y < -t[1])
            change.top = Math.max(change.top, -(c.y + t[1]));
        // bottom clipping
        if ((c.y + c.height) > (m.height - t[1]))
            change.bottom = Math.max(change.bottom, (c.y + c.height) - (m.height - t[1]));
    })

    return change;
}
```

And this is how it fits in with the rest of the flow - where `chart` is your C3 chart object

```
var change = getPaddingChange(chart);

chart.internal.config.padding_top = chart.internal.getCurrentPaddingTop() + change.top;
chart.internal.config.padding_bottom = chart.internal.getCurrentPaddingBottom() + change.bottom;
chart.internal.config.padding_left = chart.internal.getCurrentPaddingLeft() + change.left;
chart.internal.config.padding_right = chart.internal.getCurrentPaddingRight() + change.right;
// force a redraw
chart.flush();

// remove clip path
chart.internal.main.select('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.chart).attr('clip-path', null);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/b7ns8muv/

I stubbed out the underscore.js function calls.

---

Here's how it looks before and after the adjustment. Note that took off the clippath from the 'before' chart too to give a better idea of the adjustment.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting clipping after implementing your code @potatopeelings. The new code seems to change the padding very slightly on my chart, but not enough to prevent clipping. I've added the updated code in my original post.

Comment: There's a couple of things missing from your code - the definition of extractPointsFromGrid and gridData. Maybe you could update the fiddle in my answer with some data? Cheers!

Comment: I tried to add the missing code, but I'm running into a syntax error: http://jsfiddle.net/b7ns8muv/1/

Comment: Ok, fixed the data and syntax error in the fiddle, but the graph actually works correctly. Not sure what I'm missing in my code locally. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b7ns8muv/3/

Comment: Looks like we're using an old version of c3 because of ie 8/9 compatibility issues, and that's what's causing the clipping issue to recur even with your suggested fix.

Comment: After updating our c3.js reference to the newest version, your solution worked. Thanks!